I need to capture objects in the image, but I'm missing the objects I need to find

Image before detection

Image after detection


import cv2
import os

def crop_images(input_path, output_dir):
  
    image = cv2.imread(input_path)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)

    _, thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
    
    kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (11, 11))
    dilate = cv2.dilate(thresh, kernel, iterations=1)
    
    cnts, _ = cv2.findContours(dilate, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

 
    image_with_rectangles = image.copy()  
    
    image_number = 0
    min_roi_size = 7000
    max_roi_size = 30000
    for c in cnts:
        x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        
     
        if max_roi_size > w * h > min_roi_size:
            cv2.rectangle(image_with_rectangles, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2) 
            ROI = image[y:y + h, x:x + w]
            output_path = os.path.join(output_dir, f"ROI_{image_number}.jpg")
            cv2.imwrite(output_path, ROI)
            image_number += 1

    cv2.imwrite(("image_with_rectangles.jpg"), image_with_rectangles)

The bottom-left portion of the original image often gets overlooked, with some details missing, but I can't adjust it.

You don't need max_roi_size, there is no any other object bigger than the objects of your interest, or at least it should be very big. So quick fix would be to set max_roi_size some bigger number, let's say 40000: max_roi_size = 40000.


Thank you for your advice. I'm just a beginner in computer vision, so what I'm doing is learning from those who came before me.
